# Bigquery cloud function

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to create a cloud function with a dataflow script that goes from BigQuery back to BigQuery. Our main table is huge and has multiple nested fields which breaks the extract capabilities. We would like to create multiple simple tables that can be extracted containing all the relevant information for visualization. Query should execute only if there is a change in Main table.

Comment: I don't quite get the problem you're trying to solve. Also, why is your _"main table huge"_ and what is _"huge"_? Is it partitioned or clustered?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions does not support [yet hopefully] triggers based on BigQuery events

As of today, Cloud Functions supports the following native trigger mechanisms:

- HTTP Triggers
- Cloud Pub/Sub Triggers
- Cloud Storage Triggers
- Direct Triggers
- Cloud Firestore
- Analytics for Firebase
- Realtime Database

see more at [Calling Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/)